# No data received from term stores after Cumulative update August 2018

Tags: term-store, managed-metadata-column

After passing the update on my SP 2013 servers.
The term store is no longer reachable for my metadata columns.
therefore, all these metadatas columns are grayed out in the forms.

I've checked the Service application and the proxy from my CA, both are running.

Any idea why it's not available? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After investigating the ULS log, I found out that some user rights on registry have been during the update causing the Metadata service to be down.

I found this blog explaining why and giving the solution to my issue:
https://sharepointologic.blogspot.com/2014/02/managed-metadata-service-not-working.html

I managed to fix it by using this command (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513047(v=office.14).aspx):

`psconfig -cmd secureresources`